# Angularjs redirect to state using a url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

Usually if I want to send a user to a specific state, I just do:

```
$state.go('state_name');
$state.transitionTo('state_name');
```

And that will usually bring them to `/state_name`. However, I have a particular state that I am trying to send them to that has a variable in it like `/state_name/:variable` and I can't seem to figure out how to redirect them to `/state_name/whatever_I_choose`.

Can anyone help me figure this out? I am using `ui-router` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$state.go` which call `$state.transitionTo` internally

For passing variable in route you could have pass json with list of `params` with there values. `$scope.variable` is changed from the controller that would pass value while redirecting.

```
$state.go('state_name',{variable: $scope.variable });
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables usually going in url not in state name,  like this

```
$stateProvider
 .state('state_name', {
    url: "/state_name/:Id",
    templateUrl: 'state_name.html',
    controller: stateCtrl
})
```